# UITableView Cell loaded from nib is not displaying background color

Tags: ios6, uitableview

I am loading a UITableView cell from a nib file in a UITableViewController and the background color that I set in Interface Builder is not being displayed. Why not?

Comment: Only thing that springs to mind is perhaps its subviews are opaque? I've made that mistake before.

Comment: I checked and they were not. I went ahead and made the cell background color clear in the nib and changed the tableview's background color and that worked, But I really want to be able to have cells of different colors. That solution only works if they all have the same color obviously... Anything else come to mind?

Comment: Try adding a view to the cell under all the others that and set the background color there. That way you can have whatever color you want per cell.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` to set a background color, as Apple recommends in the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html):

> A table view sends a `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` message to its delegate just before it draws a row. If the delegate chooses to implement this method, it can make last-minute changes to the cell object before it is displayed. With this method, the delegate should change only state-based properties that were set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color, and not content.

This code does an alternating "zebra stripe" effect:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        UIColor *altCellColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.7 alpha:0.1];
        cell.backgroundColor = altCellColor;
    }
}
```